# Munin's fw_conntrack reports strange number of sockets in TIME_WAIT

Tags: ubuntu, unix, monitoring, munin

- Ubuntu Server 10.04.1 x86
- Munin 1.4.4

Here is what Munin tells me about connections through firewall on my server:

[image: TIME_WAIT]

Here is what `netstat -n` has to say about this:

```
$ netstat -an|awk '/tcp/ {print $6}'|sort|uniq -c
      2 CLOSE_WAIT
      1 CLOSING
   3720 ESTABLISHED
     34 FIN_WAIT1
     21 FIN_WAIT2
     13 LAST_ACK
      6 LISTEN
      4 SYN_RECV
    394 TIME_WAIT
```

According to `netstat`, 10% of sockets are in `TIME_WAIT`; 75% or more, according to Munin.

That is strange. Who is right?

More details about configuration etc. here: [How to reduce number of sockets in TIME_WAIT?](https://serverfault.com/questions/212093/how-to-reduce-number-of-sockets-in-time-wait)

Comment: Here is what Munin does: http://munin-monitoring.org/browser/tags/1.4.4/plugins/node.d.linux/fw_conntrack.in

Comment: Munin looks at `/proc/net/ip_contrack`. Indeed, it reports 19K connections in `TIME_WAIT` out of total 20K. The question is, who to believe?

Comment: Or am I trying to compare apples with oranges? If so, which Munin graph should I use?

Comment: Link down............

Answer (score 5, accepted):

netstat doesn't show connections that are passing through the server as a gateway / firewall.

The munin-plugin parses `/proc/net/ip_conntrack`, which contains a lot of information not visible in netstat.

The answer; Both are right, but they answer different questions.  Netstat talks about connections to and from the server itself.  Conntrack provides information about traffic passing the server, so it can make sure to do address translation and so forth correctly.