# MySQL lowering wait_timeout value to lower number of open connections

Tags: mysql, tuning

I run a rather busy site, and during peek hours I see over 10.000 open connections to my database server on my webserver when a run a netstat command. 99% of the connections are in the `TIME_WAIT` state.

I learned about this mysql variable: `wait_timeout` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout today. Mine is still set at the default 28.800 seconds.

Is lowering this value safe?

Non of my queries usually takes over a second. So it seems silly to keep a connection open for 480 minutes.

I also heard about using `mysql_pconnect` instead of `mysql_connect`, but i've been reading nothing but horror stories about it, so I think i'll stay away from that.

Comment: There's a difference between queries and connections. You need to at least ensure your web site software won't break if a shorter `wait_timeout` cause a connection to close when the software expects it to remain open.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Lowering the value is pretty trivial without a mysql restart

Let's say you want to lower timeouts to 30 seconds

First, add this to my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
interactive_timeout=30
wait_timeout=30
```

Then, you can do something like this

```
mysql -uroot -ppassword -e"SET GLOBAL wait_timeout=30; SET GLOBAL interactive_timeout=30"
```

All DB Connections after this will timeout in 30 seconds

### WARNING

Make sure to use explicitly use mysql_close. I do not trust Apache as most developers do. If not, sometimes, there is a race condition where Apache closes a DB Connection but does not inform mysqld and mysqld hold that connection open until it times out. Even worse, you may see TIME_WAITs more often. Choose your timeout values wisely.

## UPDATE 2012-11-12 10:10 EDT

### CAVEAT

After applying my posted suggestions, create a script called `/root/show_mysql_netstat.sh` with the following lines:

```
netstat | grep mysql > /root/mysql_netstat.txt
cat /root/mysql_netstat.txt | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/:/ /g' | awk '{print $2}' | sort -u > /root/mysql_netstat_iplist.txt
for IP in `cat /root/mysql_netstat_iplist.txt`
do
        ESCOUNT=`cat /root/mysql_netstat.txt | grep ESTABLISHED | awk '{print $5}' | grep -c "${IP}"`
        TWCOUNT=`cat /root/mysql_netstat.txt | grep TIME_WAIT   | awk '{print $5}' | grep -c "${IP}"`
        IPPAD=`echo "${IP}..................................." | cut -b -35`
        (( ESCOUNT += 1000000 ))
        (( TWCOUNT += 1000000 ))
        ES=`echo ${ESCOUNT} | cut -b 3-`
        TW=`echo ${TWCOUNT} | cut -b 3-`
        echo ${IPPAD} : ESTABLISHED:${ES} TIME_WAIT:${TW}
done
echo ; echo
netstat -nat | awk '{print $6}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | sed 's/d)/d/'
```

When you run this, you should see something like this:

```
[root@*** ~]# /root/ShowConnProfiles.sh
10.48.22.4......................... : ESTABLISHED:00002 TIME_WAIT:00008
10.48.22.8......................... : ESTABLISHED:00000 TIME_WAIT:00002
10.64.51.130....................... : ESTABLISHED:00001 TIME_WAIT:00000
10.64.51.133....................... : ESTABLISHED:00000 TIME_WAIT:00079
10.64.51.134....................... : ESTABLISHED:00002 TIME_WAIT:00001
10.64.51.17........................ : ESTABLISHED:00003 TIME_WAIT:01160
10.64.51.171....................... : ESTABLISHED:00002 TIME_WAIT:00000
10.64.51.174....................... : ESTABLISHED:00000 TIME_WAIT:00589
10.64.51.176....................... : ESTABLISHED:00001 TIME_WAIT:00570


      1 established
      1 Foreign
     11 LISTEN
     25 ESTABLISHED
   1301 TIME_WAIT
```

If you still see a lot of mysql `TIME_WAITs` for any given web server, here are two escalation steps to take:

### ESCALATION #1

Login to the offending web server and restart apache as follows:

```
service httpd stop
sleep 30
service httpd start
```

If necessary, do this to all the web servers

```
service httpd stop (on all web servers)
service mysql stop
sleep 120
service mysql start
service httpd start (on all web servers)
```

### ESCALATION #2

You can force the OS to kill TIME_WAITs for mysql or any other app with the following:

```
SEC_TO_TIMEWAIT=1
echo ${SEC_TO_TIMEWAIT} > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_recycle
echo ${SEC_TO_TIMEWAIT} > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse
```

This will make TIME_WAITs time out in 1 second.

## To give credit where credit is due...

- I got this idea from this post: [How to forcibly close a socket in TIME_WAIT?](https://serverfault.com/questions/329845/how-to-forcibly-close-a-socket-in-time-wait)
- [**The accepted answer**](https://serverfault.com/a/329846/69271) has a pictorial representation of when a `TIME_WAIT` comes into existence.
- [The answer with the idea that I liked is the one I am now suggesting](https://serverfault.com/a/329848/69271).

Comment: Nearly 2k views for this and only 2 up votes (including mine, so 1), wtf?! This is a great answer. Sorry I can only give 1 up vote!

Comment: I tried this technique, and I had a lot of CLOSE_WAIT connections (2622) but not TIME_WAIT connections. How should I interpret this result?

Comment: Escalation #2 is dangerous!! https://serverfault.com/a/715883

Answer (score 4):

If you are getting a lot of TIME_WAIT connections on the MySQL Server then that means that MySQL server is closing the connection.  The most likely case in this instance would be that  a host or several hosts got on a block list.  You can clear this by running:

```
mysqladmin flush-hosts
```

To get a list of the number of connections you have per IP run:

```
 netstat -nat | awk {'print $5'} | cut -d ":" -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

You can also confirm this is happening by going to one of your clients that is having trouble connecting and telnet to port 3306.  It will show a message with something like:

```
telnet mysqlserver 3306
Trying 192.168.1.102...
Connected to mysqlserver.
Escape character is '^]'.
sHost 'clienthost.local' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have lots of TIME_WAIT connections to your MySQL server, it means you code is running lots of queries against your DB, and opening/closing a connection for each query.

In this case, you should use persistent connectivity to your DB server, using the MySQLi extension.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php

If you can't use MySQLi, you should instead use the thread_cache_size parameter in your MySQL configuration.