# How to monitor socket connection usage and exhaustion on a server?

Tags: ubuntu, network-monitoring, socket

I have a service endpoint (java) that will be getting bursts of thousands of requests per second.

In my load testing I had to tweak the server because I would run out of open sockets as there were many stuck in various status levels similiar to: [How to reduce number of sockets in TIME_WAIT?](https://serverfault.com/questions/212093/how-to-reduce-number-of-sockets-in-time-wait)

I'm running Ubuntu, how can I collect the correct stats for this to send to nagios or monit?

Comment: How did you know the server was running out of sockets?

Comment: @MarkWagner It wasn't excepting any new connections during load testing.  And the number of sockets was at 32K roughly.  It was a while ago but I believe they were in the TIME_WAIT status.

Comment: That doesn't indicate sockets were exhausted. It could be your app can't process the connections fast enough and only so many TCP connections can be backlogged (`/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_max_syn_backlog`), which has nothing to do with socket exhaustion.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the ss utility.

```
ss -an
```